# determine mouse location on an image

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

how do i determine the mouse location on an image using javascript when mouse is clicked

Answer (score 7):

trimmed version of the solution linked by geeketteSpeaks:

```js
function getImageCoords(event, img) {
  var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
  var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - img.offsetTop;
  alert("You clicked at: (" + posX + "," + posY + ")");
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" onclick="getImageCoords(event,this);">
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/

Comment: Link-only answers aren't considered good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer